# Redefining a variable inside a newcommand

Tags: macros

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\cm}
\setlength{\cm}{1cm}
\newcommand\scalefactor{2}

\newcommand{\bintree}[5]{
\protect{\renewcommand\scalefactor{#5}}
\resizebox{\scalefactor\cm}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw (0,0)--(0,.5);%
\draw (0,.5)--(-.5,1);%
\draw (0,.5)--(.5,1);%

\node[below] at (0,0){#3};%
\node[above] at (-.5,1){#1};%
\node[above] at (.5,1){#2};%
\node[right] at (0,.4){#4};%
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\begin{document}

\bintree{$s$}{$s$}{$s$}{$*$}{1}
\bintree{$s$}{$s$}{$s$}{$*$}{3}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work (I don't get the rescaling I would like). Here's what I obtain:

[image]

and nothing in the log. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: the posted code does not give the error you state, so presumably it is from some code you do not show, Please post an example that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Wait, I'll edit my question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There, done. Actually now I have a completely different problem. I have no idea where the error came from...

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud: Fragments of code are not really useful, in my point of view

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This is my whole macro for now. I run it in a document simply by calling \bintree{}{}{}{}{3} (for example).

Comment: `\protect{` will _always_ give an error

Comment: Your enlarged example still does not produce the error stated, I get `! LaTeX Error: \usepackage before \documentclass.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually, now I don't get any errors. Just the \scalefactor which is applied by my code is the one given in my 5th line of code (\newcommand\scalefactor{2}), and not the input argument.

Comment: You presumably get errors from the code above. If you do not, please _post the code you are using!!!!_

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I put it all together in a single document. In 2 minutes I will also post the output.

Comment: why doesn't your macro use `#5` is that supposed to be the scale factor? (and tikz can scale internally you shouldn't need resizebox should you?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, I was experimenting and I forgot to change it back. The output is still the same. Sorry I am not an expert with tikz, I will look up automatic rescaling.

Comment: and please next time post a complete document, as you see, it is impossible to answer the question without that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had done the redefinition inside a group so you could do

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\cm}
\setlength{\cm}{1cm}
\newcommand\scalefactor{2}

\newcommand{\bintree}[5]{%
\renewcommand\scalefactor{#5}%
\resizebox{\scalefactor\cm}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw (0,0)--(0,.5);%
\draw (0,.5)--(-.5,1);%
\draw (0,.5)--(.5,1);%

\node[below] at (0,0){#3};%
\node[above] at (-.5,1){#1};%
\node[above] at (.5,1){#2};%
\node[right] at (0,.4){#4};%
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\begin{document}

\bintree{$s$}{$s$}{$s$}{$*$}{1}
\bintree{$s$}{$s$}{$s$}{$*$}{3}

\end{document}
```

although you didn't need `\cm` or `\scalefactor` at all you could just do

```
  \resizebox{#5cm}
```

and never apply `\protect` to `{` it can never do anything useful and will usually generate weird errors.

Comment: It works. So the problem was protect? I'm really, really confused about my code right now...

Comment: Probably one should wrap the `\renewcommand` in a group not to leave `\scalefactor` in a different state than before.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud the `\protect` theer was doing nothing, so you have `{  \renewcommand\xxx{zzz} }` with the `{}` forming a group (not delimiting an argument to `\protect` which never takes a brace delimited argument) so the redefinition was undone at the `}` as always happens with tex groups

Comment: @egreg I'd guess it is only used in this macro and reset everytime so it's harmeless (and not needed anyway)

Comment: Ok, thanks, this makes it a bit clearer. I still have a lot to learn about the inner workings of TeX...